# CREAR UN ARCHIVO EN TODOS LOS SUBDIRECTORIOS UTILIZANDO COMANDO FOR EN VENTANA CMD

Tags: bucle-for, cmd

quisera crear un batch o desde la ventana cmd bajo el siguiente caso: Tengo una directorio que contiene varias carpetas y asu vez cada carpeta tiene un archivo word, quisiera crear un nuevo archivo vacio txt en cada carpeta, pero que tenga el nombre del archivo que ya existe las carpetas

Comment: Hola Miguel, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece a "tengo este ejercicio, háganlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.